# Bash to select by wildcard any filename without extension

Tags: bash, wildcards

How bash select by wildcard any filename without extension as doing it end in falure? e.g.

```
$ ls /source/c
m m.asm m.c m.d m-0 m-1 

$ cp -ru /source/c/*. ~/Downloads/c
cp: cannot stat '/source/c/*.': No such file or directory
```

to copy only m m-0 m-1

Please help ! is invaluably gratified, thanks.

Comment: In case of `.bashrc`, is `bashrc` an extension? How about `com` in `unix.stackexchange.com`? (which may be the name of a file). How about the empty substring after `.` in `foo.`? My point is the concept of extension is (somewhat) well-defined in DOS/Windows, but not in \*nix. Except *maybe* when dealing with a filesystem that uses extensions internally (e.g. FAT with its 8.3 scheme). "Filenames without dots", "filenames without non-leading dots", "filenames, except ones with at most three characters after the last dot" – these are reasonably well-defined conditions.

Comment: Your pattern `*.` would match any name that ends with a dot. Is this what you mean by a name without an extension? Or, are you wanting to match names that does not contain a dot at all? Please clarify this. Also mention if you are at all concerned with _hidden_ names (names _starting with a dot_).

Comment: @Kusalananda, *to copy only m m-0 m-1* makes it rather clear what they want. I'll agree `*.` is a weird attempt to solve that problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, the code clarifies it, but there is a sort of logic to the `*.` pattern too, as it would match names that lacks an extension (the string after the dot, which `:e` would return in `zsh`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, it might be that `*.` works in DOS or Windows, as they seem to treat the dot in some weird special way. Like rejecting filenames that end in a dot (https://superuser.com/questions/230385/dots-at-the-end-of-file-name) (apperently MS Teams also rejects files/folders with names like that)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid filenames with a dot, use the extended glob expression `!(*.*)` instead of `*.`:

```bash
cp -ru /source/c/!(*.*) ~/Downloads/c/
```

In Bash, that's controlled by the `extglob` option, so if you get an error you will have to turn it on using `shopt -s extglob`. If you want to turn it off, use `shopt -u extglob`.

If wanting to copy hidden files, for which you also need `shopt -s dotglob`, you may also want to exclude filenames such as `.bashrc` which may be considered as not having an *extension* (a not well defined concept in Unix):

```
cp -ru /source/c/!(?*.*) ~/Downloads/c/
```